# finding a number in a dictionary and printing in python

Tags: python, dictionary

```
A = int(input("A: "))

B = int(input("B: "))
```

I have a dictionary = `{"11": 1, "05": 2, "04": 3, "03": 4, "02": 5, "01": 6}`

If I input `A = 2, B = 4`,

the code has print the dictionary from `02` to `04`.

I don't want to use slicing, but I can't find a way to do this.

Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple for loop here like this:

```
d = {"11": 1, "05": 2, "04": 3, "03": 4, "02": 5, "01": 6}

A = int(input("A: "))
B = int(input("B: "))

for k,v in d.items():
    if int(k) >= A and int(k) <= B:
        print(k,v)
```

You could also use the `filter` function to return an iterator to items in the dictionary you're interested in:

```
it = filter(lambda item: int(item[0]) >= A and int(item[0]) <= B, d.items())
for item in it:
    print(item)
```

Or you could use a dictionary comprehension to get a new dictionary of filtered items:

```
sub_dict = {k:v for k,v in d.items() if int(k) >= A and int(k) <= B}
print(sub_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could manually construct the keys from the inputs by:

- converting the inputs to integers
- making a range from `range(A, B+1)`
- convert the outputs of the range function back to stings with leading zero
- ...

edit:

Example w/ simple loop:

```
a = {   "07": 3,
        "08": 99,
        "09": 2,
        "10": 55,
        "11": -5,
        "12": 1}

A = 8    # result of input()...
B = 11

keys = []
for i in range(A, B+1):
    if i <10:
        temp = ''.join(['0', str(i)])
        keys.append(temp)
    else:
        keys.append(str(i))


for key in keys:
    print(key, a.get(key))
```

Comment: I have considered this, but what is there is {"11": 5} in the dictionary? Then the solution of leading zero wouldn't work.

Comment: Well, you'd need to define some rules for what the keys are in the dictionary.  If it is just that there is a leading zero for numbers less than 10, you could handle that case with a conditional statement for the addition of the leading zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
A = int(input("A: "))

B = int(input("B: "))

dictionary = {"05": 1, "04": 2, "03": 3, "02": 4, "01": 5}

for n in range(A, B):
    print(dictionary[f"{n+1}.zfill(2)])
```

Output:

```
A: 2
B: 4
3
2
```